# How to download a file on click of a view in android

Tags: android

**What i am having ?**

Here `patientAttachment.getFile_path()` have the link of the url that has image
.

---

```
 vObjPatientMedication.downloadId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse(patientAttachment.getFile_path()));
                activity.startActivity(myWebLink);

            }
        });
```

**What now is happening**: i am displaying the image in browser

**What i am trying to achieve**: i want to initiate the download of that file(file can be pdf/image/word) to any default location where downloading is taken care by android.

**How to achieve this ?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html):

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(uriString));
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

You should also register a receiver to know when a download completes:

```
registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
            //Your code
        }
    }
};
```